# Playwright - timeout in config is 2mins but i want to wait for 5mins in one my test case without change in the config waittime

Tags: typescript, ui-automation, playwright, playwright-test

I have a timeout for 2 mins in PlaywrightTestConfig file as a Global setting. In one of the test case I want to wait for  10 mins for a file validation to happen.
Global setting for all tests is defined like below:

```
const config: PlaywrightTestConfig = {
  // Timeout for each Playwright action in milliseconds. Defaults to 0 (no timeout)
  timeout: 120000
  ...
}
```

I tried these ways:

1. click({ timeout: 600000 });
2. test.slow();
3. test.setTimeout(600000);
4. page.setDefaultTimeout(600000);
5. page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout(600000);

In all these cases, the test timesout after 2 mins instead of the overwrite 10 mins(600000).

Bumping up the global setting might work, but it will make the whole test suite run slower which is not ideal.

Is it possible to have timeout for a step be more than the global timeout?

Comment: 60000 milliseconds is 10 minutes, not 5. Check out [`page.setDefaultTimeout`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-set-default-timeout).

Comment: Both page.setDefaultTimeout and page.setDefaultNavigationTimeout did not work @ggorlen

Comment: Is the test timeout also set https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts?

Comment: Yes. Updated the description with code on how the test timeout is set. @ggorlen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Have custom timeout on specific action+ [test timeout](https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts#test-timeout):**

Specific action inside Page Object :

```
 async performSomeAction() {
  //some test steps
   await page.click(someLocator)
   await page.waitForSelector(locatorWhichAppearAfterClick,{timeout:400000})
  //some other steps
}
```

Inside Test:

```
test('Perform someAction', async () => {
    await page.performSomeAction()  
  },600000)
```

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/test-timeouts

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like there are different types of tests in your suite. One possible approach to separate them based on duration is to split them into projects. Then for each project you can specify different `timeout` instead of having one global value which doesn't fit all use cases.

```
{
  "use": [
    {
      "browserName": "chromium",
      "timeout": 120000
    },
    {
      "browserName": "chromium",
      "timeout": 600000,
      "testMatch": '/long-tasks/**/*.spec.js',
    }
  ]
}
```